# How to implement Socket.io with next.js without separate node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, next.js

I want to build a chat system with Next.js. I am not sure how I have to setup the socket server.

I want this to implement Next server not with a separate server.
Should I have to make a server.js file in root and run a server?

Comment: When I google "nextjs socket.io" I get a bunch of promising results; have you looked into these yet?

Comment: Yes. But none of them are satisfactory for me!!

Comment: You need to add to your question the specific code you've tried, and a description of why it fails, including relevant error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) however, then you can't deploy to vercel, and you got yourself a regular nodejs application.
You could use *cloud* providers to handle sockets for you, or as you said, you could split your application to a regular next.js app and deploy your socket application separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to use socket.io on the same server as next.js.

I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/bibekoli/socket-nextjs) implementing this thing.
It is a very simple and working starter template for Next.js and socket.io.